# [Python][Tkinter] adding a flag to make the label's foreground turn to red in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, flags

So I can't seem to figure out how to approach this dilemma that I have.
I have a simple script that basically prints out 5 labels, each print out 1 after another with a pause of 2 seconds.

What I wanted to do is basically highlight the currently running label in 'red' and then when the 2nd label prints out the 1st label's foreground should return to 'black' and so on. So basically the last label should be in red and the previous ones should be in black.

Basically, the purpose of this is that I have an automation script written in python to test an Android TV and I want to make a simple GUI for it. I want to highlight the current test case that is running. After the function(test case) executed then I want it to turn to black.

Code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import time

class SampleTkinterLoop:

    def __init__(self, master):
        # Initialize master as the Tk() instance
        self.master = master
        master.title("Loop Tests")
        master.geometry("768x480")

        # Create main frame as app
        self.app = ttk.Frame(root)
        self.app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # Create a custom font
        self.mainFont = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12)

        # Initialize flags for BG and FG change
        self.bgCounter = 0

    def test1(self):
        x = True # set fgChooser to True to make foreground red
        ttk.Label(
            self.app, text=f'Test case 1',
            background=self.bgChooser(),
            foreground=self.fgChooser(x),
            font=self.mainFont).pack()
        self.bgCounter += 1
        x = False # set it back to false to make foreround black
        root.update()  # allow window to catch up
        time.sleep(2)

    def test2(self):
        x = True # set fgChooser to True to make foreground red
        ttk.Label(
            self.app, text=f'Test case 2',
            background=self.bgChooser(),
            foreground=self.fgChooser(x),
            font=self.mainFont).pack()
        self.bgCounter += 1
        x = False # set it back to false to make foreround black
        root.update()  # allow window to catch up
        time.sleep(2)

    def test3(self):
        x = True # set fgChooser to True to make foreground red
        ttk.Label(
            self.app, text=f'Test case 3',
            background=self.bgChooser(),
            foreground=self.fgChooser(x),
            font=self.mainFont).pack()
        self.bgCounter += 1
        x = False # set it back to false to make foreround black
        root.update()  # allow window to catch up
        time.sleep(2)

    def test4(self):
        x = True # set fgChooser to True to make foreground red
        ttk.Label(
            self.app, text=f'Test case 4',
            background=self.bgChooser(),
            foreground=self.fgChooser(x),
            font=self.mainFont).pack()
        self.bgCounter += 1
        x = False # set it back to false to make foreround black
        root.update()  # allow window to catch up
        time.sleep(2)

    def test5(self):
        x = True # set fgChooser to True to make foreground red
        ttk.Label(
            self.app, text=f'Test case 5',
            background=self.bgChooser(),
            foreground=self.fgChooser(x),
            font=self.mainFont).pack()
        self.bgCounter += 1
        x = False # set it back to false to make foreround black
        root.update()  # allow window to catch up
        time.sleep(2)

    def repeatIt(self):
        for i in range(0, 5):
            # self.anotherLoop()
            self.test1()
            self.test2()
            self.test3()
            self.test4()
            self.test5()
            self.reset()
            root.update()
            time.sleep(1)
            print(i)

    def bgChooser(self):
        # make label background alternate to white and gray for easy reading
        if (self.bgCounter % 2) == 0:
            return str("#fff")
        return str("#ccc")

    def fgChooser(self, isActive=False):
        # this is where the  problem is, can't seem to find a way to make a flag for foreground color of label
        if isActive:
            return str("#a5120d")
        return str("#000")

    def reset(self):
        '''reset the UI'''
        for child in self.app.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()

root = Tk()
LoopTest = SampleTkinterLoop(root)
LoopTest.repeatIt()
root.mainloop()
```

The code above makes all label red, it does not turn the previous label to black.

Comment: I need a bit of clarification about what the other parts of your code mean. For example, what does the `def bgChooser(self)` part do exactly? And what is the intended purpose of the "dumb not working" code `self.fgActive = False` supposed to do? According to the code that I see, you are implying that `self.fgActive = False` is probably what you suspect is the problem that requires fixing.

Comment: so the bgChooser() is the background of the label. white and gray alternately. the fgChooser() is the flag that i came up with but it does not work so i removed the call for it. what i originally did was pass true on fgChooser before the label call then pass false after the label call, but what it does is make all my label red.

Comment: So far, I only see new label backgrounds turn white then grey then repeating again. You may want to get a piece of code that automatically makes the next label's background as red, and then make the label above turn to its respective expected color.

Comment: oh sorry, my question was not clear. background is actually ok. what i want is the foreground of the label in red.

Comment: So is the only problem with the program that the foreground of the label doesn't turn red? And what exactly what do you want to happen to make the foreground of the label red?

Comment: I also need to note that `fgActive` might need declaration. I am not sure if `fgActive` is a custom function, but I don't think you've declared this function yet.

Comment: alright so I updated the code, fgActive is actually not used so I removed it. The program's label turns red but all labels are red. Basically, the purpose of this is that I have a script written in python and I want to make a simple GUI for it. I want to highlight the current test case that is running. After the function executed then I want it to turn to black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `ttk` for that task. Its because you can change the label color later.
For example:
Importings:

```
from tkinter import *  #<-- so you don't have to edit your full code
import tkinter as ttk     #<---
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import time
```

You can edit your `test1` function like:

```
x = True 
xyz = ttk.Label(   #assign to a variable rather than packing <---
    self.app, text=f'Test case 1',
    background=self.bgChooser(),
    foreground=self.fgChooser(x),
    font=self.mainFont)
xyz.pack()   #pack later  <---
self.bgCounter += 1
x = False 
root.update()
time.sleep(2)
xyz.config(fg="black")   #change color after 2 sec  <---
```

Here is an example code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import time

class SampleTkinterLoop:

    def __init__(self, master):
        # Initialize master as the Tk() instance
        self.master = master
        master.title("Loop Tests")
        master.geometry("768x480")

        # Create main frame as app
        self.app = ttk.Frame(root)
        self.app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # Create a custom font
        self.mainFont = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12)

        # Initialize flags for BG and FG change
        self.bgCounter = 0

    def test1(self):
        x = True # set fgChooser to True to make foreground red
        xyz = ttk.Label(
            self.app, text=f'Test case 1',
            background=self.bgChooser(),
            foreground=self.fgChooser(x),
            font=self.mainFont)
        xyz.pack()
        self.bgCounter += 1
        x = False # set it back to false to make foreround black
        root.update()  # allow window to catch up
        time.sleep(2)
        xyz.config(fg="black")

    def test2(self):
        x = True # set fgChooser to True to make foreground red
        xyz = ttk.Label(
            self.app, text=f'Test case 2',
            background=self.bgChooser(),
            foreground=self.fgChooser(x),
            font=self.mainFont)
        xyz.pack()
        self.bgCounter += 1
        x = False # set it back to false to make foreround black
        root.update()  # allow window to catch up
        time.sleep(2)
        xyz.config(fg="black")

    def test3(self):
        x = True # set fgChooser to True to make foreground red
        xyz = ttk.Label(
            self.app, text=f'Test case 3',
            background=self.bgChooser(),
            foreground=self.fgChooser(x),
            font=self.mainFont)
        xyz.pack()
        self.bgCounter += 1
        x = False # set it back to false to make foreround black
        root.update()  # allow window to catch up
        time.sleep(2)
        xyz.config(fg="black")

    def test4(self):
        x = True # set fgChooser to True to make foreground red
        xyz = ttk.Label(
            self.app, text=f'Test case 4',
            background=self.bgChooser(),
            foreground=self.fgChooser(x),
            font=self.mainFont)
        xyz.pack()
        self.bgCounter += 1
        x = False # set it back to false to make foreround black
        root.update()  # allow window to catch up
        time.sleep(2)
        xyz.config(fg="black")

    def test5(self):
        x = True # set fgChooser to True to make foreground red
        xyz = ttk.Label(
            self.app, text=f'Test case 5',
            background=self.bgChooser(),
            foreground=self.fgChooser(x),
            font=self.mainFont)
        xyz.pack()
        self.bgCounter += 1
        x = False # set it back to false to make foreround black
        root.update()  # allow window to catch up
        time.sleep(2)
        xyz.config(fg="black")

    def repeatIt(self):
        for i in range(0, 5):
            # self.anotherLoop()
            self.test1()
            self.test2()
            self.test3()
            self.test4()
            self.test5()
            self.reset()
            root.update()
            time.sleep(1)
            print(i)

    def bgChooser(self):
        # make label background alternate to white and gray for easy reading
        if (self.bgCounter % 2) == 0:
            return str("#fff")
        return str("#ccc")

    def fgChooser(self, isActive=False):
        # this is where the  problem is, can't seem to find a way to make a flag for foreground color of label
        if isActive:
            return str("#a5120d")
        return str("#000")

    def reset(self):
        '''reset the UI'''
        for child in self.app.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()

root = Tk()
LoopTest = SampleTkinterLoop(root)
LoopTest.repeatIt()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: awesome! thank you so much! and in this case, I don't really need the function fgChooser since I can just change the foreground after the pause.